# Fedora Nautilus 3.26 Icon Alignment Problem or Bug: Icons are misaligned

Tags: fedora, gnome3, nautilus

Nautilus 3.26 does not show icons normally, but before I upgraded to nautilus 3.26, in nautilus 3.24 icons  are shown normally without any problem. Nautilus 3.26 shows icons like the following picture. How can I fix it ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lUn5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade pango library used for text rendering. This solved my problem.

```
sudo dnf downgrade pango-1.40.12-1.fc27.x86_64 pango-1.40.12-1.fc27.i686
```